# Function Find in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Good Afternoon,

I have a small query that is buggin the hell out of me. Is there anyone here that can help me find what i'm doing wrong exactly ?
I'm trying to find an employee id in a different sheet that needs to be searched in 25000 rows with the following VBA code (keep in mind the employee id is due to change on every search)

```
Dim id As Range, rng As Range

Set id = Sheets("TeamList").Cells(5, 7)

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Select.Columns(20).Find(what:=id, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False).Select

Set id = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
```

When i run this code i receive an error 91 [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRH1f.png)

Example of id used [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAIV3.png) - I should also mentione that this id is formated as value (multiplyed by 1, i need them in this format for different usage under a bigger file)

### Update 08/02/2017

I have manage to sort out the code: Changed the Dim's from range to strings and removed the "Set" but added "cells".
  See example below:

```
Dim id As String, hrs As String

 id = Sheets("TeamList").Cells(5, 7)
 hrs = Sheets("TeamList").Cells(4, 7)

   Sheets("Sheet1").Select

      Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:=id, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Comment: change to `Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(20).Find(what:=id, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)`

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply, however its still not working

Answer (score 1):

Drop the select. Also good practice to check first that the value is found.

```
Dim id As Range, rng As Range

Set id = Sheets("TeamList").Cells(5, 7)

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(20).Find(what:=id, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
If not rng is nothing then application.goto rng

Set id = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fully debug your code, but in general `id` should be a **value** rather than a **Range** Object. ( so the ***Set*** should not be used for `id`).

Also if the `Set` works for `rng`, before `Selecting` rng you should first Select or Activate the worksheet containing `rng`.

Comment: Hi, thank you @gary's student for your reply, well i only set it as a range as the id is always going to changed depending on the person i need to search. So a fixed value within the vba won't help me.